# Bootstrap modal doesn't launch on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal that is loaded via data-remote. In the modal body, I include a jquery library (for example timepicker), followed by a  tag that calls functions from the library.

The problem is, the modal doesn't launch on the first click (with firebug error that a function from the library was not available). But the moal launches on the second or later clicks.

What's the best way to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: To avoid the problem rather than fix it, you can just make the first call yourself. Make a `click()` call?

Comment: Ensure your JS files are loaded in the recommended order, i.e. jquery.js, bootstrap.js, then all your custom JS.

Comment: @rybo111 jquery and bootstrap are loaded on the underlying page and work. The external library is loaded in the modal template itself, and the function in the external library is called in a <script> block that comes after the include statement. So everything seems to be loaded in order, hence my question.

Comment: You could make a fiddle with just the elements you're using, and see if the problem persists. If it does, post the fiddle link and we might be able to work out what's causing it. Also, does the same thing happen in Chrome, and do you get an identical error?